# r heatmap.2 colsep as vector

Tags: r, heatmap

I want to draw a heatmap, using heatmap.2(), in which I want to define colseps in several different colors.
I have tried specifiyng sepcolor by concatenation:

```
heatmap.2 (as.matrix(order_by27_T[rowsToDraw,]), Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE,               dendrogram="none", col=hmColors, breaks=seq(0,1,(1/120)), trace="none", colsep=c(60,120,180), sepcolor=c("white","pink","green"))
```

Further, I tried to create a character vector specfiying the desired colors in the desired order and to assign this vector to sepcolor:

```
sepColour<-c("white","pink","green")
heatmap.2 (as.matrix(order_by27_T[rowsToDraw,]), Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE, dendrogram="none", col=hmColors, breaks=seq(0,1,(1/120)), trace="none", colsep=c(60,120,180), sepcolor=sepColour)
```

In both cases, all there seprators defined were green (the last element of the vector).
Is what I'm trying to do possible at all?

thanks in advance

Comment: What package is `heatmap.2()` from?

Comment: heatmap.2() is from package gplots()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `colsep` argument takes a vector of numbers indicating whether the columns should be separated by a space of colour. From the documentation:

```
(optional) vector of integers indicating which columns or rows should be separated from the preceding columns or rows by a narrow space of color sepcolor
```

In your example, this would be something like:

```
heatmap.2(as.matrix(order_by27_T[rowsToDraw,]), colsep=1:5,
     sepcolor=c("red", "blue"), ....)
```

This would separate columns 1 to 5 with the colours `red` and `blue`

---

Just in case you only want to specify a custom palette (not what you asked for), here is some code:

```
full = matrix(runif(100, -5, 5), ncol= 10)
my_p = colorRampPalette(c("white","pink","green"))
breaks = c(seq(min(full), 0, length.out=128),
           seq(0, max(full), length.out=128))
heatmap.2(full, dendrogram="row", Colv=FALSE,
          col=my_p, key=TRUE, 
          breaks=breaks, symkey=FALSE, density.info="none",
          trace="none", cexRow=0.5, cexCol=0.75)
```

Comment: But `colsep` indicates the column. So it must be a number.

Comment: Thanks! that did what I was looking for. But I'm still not sure how to control the colors. eventually I did this:   colsep=c(25,35,60,85,95,120,155,165,180,205,215), sepcolor=c("cyan", "white"). Incidentlly I got what I wanted, which was a white colsep every 60 columns and cyan ones in between. but why?, this isn't the way vectors in R work in general. I'll add that the matrix I'm trying to plot is made up of four data frames with 60 columns each, that I combined with cbind(). Does this possibly have anything to do with the colsep evrey 60 columns bieng white? Thanks again.